# Generating primes without blowing the stack

Tags: ocaml, primes

I'm learning OCaml (so forgive my style) and am trying to write a function that generates a list of prime numbers up to some upper bound. I've managed to do this in several different ways, all of which work until you scale them to a relatively high upper bound.

How can I change these (any of them) so that the recursion doesn't fill up the stack? I thought my while loop version would achieve this, but apparently not!

### Generator

```
let primes max =
  let isPrime p x =
    let hasDivisor a = (x mod a = 0) in
    not (List.exists hasDivisor p) in

  let rec generate p test =
    if test < max then
      let nextTest = test + 2 in
      if isPrime p test then generate (test :: p) nextTest
                        else generate p nextTest
    else p in

  generate [5; 3; 2] 7;;
```

This has been my most successful solution insofar as it doesn't immediately overflow the stack when running `primes 2000000;;`. However it just sits there consuming CPU; I can only assume it will complete eventually! The following alternatives all have the stack overflow problem:

### Recursive Sieve of Eratosthenes

```
let primes max =
  let rec sieve found toTest =
    let h = List.hd toTest
    and t = List.tl toTest in

    let newPrimes = h :: found
    and doesntDivide x = (x mod h <> 0) in

    let nonDivisors = List.filter doesntDivide t in
      if nonDivisors = [] then newPrimes
                          else sieve newPrimes nonDivisors in

  let rec range a b =
    if a > b then []
             else a :: range (a + 1) b in

  let p = range 2 max in

  sieve [] p;;
```

### Recursive Sieve of Eratosthenes v2

```
let primes max =
  let rec sieve toTest =
    let h = List.hd toTest
    and t = List.tl toTest in
    let doesntDivide x = (x mod h <> 0) in
    let nonDivisors = List.filter doesntDivide t in
      if nonDivisors = [] then [h]
                          else (h :: sieve nonDivisors) in

  let rec range a b =
    if a > b then []
             else a :: range (a + 1) b in

  let p = range 2 max in

  sieve p;;
```

### While Loop Sieve of Eratosthenes

```
let primes max =
  let rec range a b =
    if a > b then []
             else a :: range (a + 1) b in

  let tail = ref (range 2 max)
  and p    = ref [] in

  while !tail <> [] do
    let h = List.hd !tail
    and t = List.tl !tail in
    let doesntDivide x = (x mod h <> 0) in
    let newTail = ref (List.filter doesntDivide t) in

    tail := !newTail;
    p := h :: !p
  done;

  !p;;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The stack overflows occur because your range function is not tail recursive.  One that works is, e.g.

```
  let rec range store a b =
    if a > b then store
    else range (a :: store) (a + 1) b
  in

  let p = List.rev (range [] 2 max) in
```

With that definition, and a format line, gives

```
$ ocamlopt -o primes2 primes2.ml
$ ./primes2
2
3
5
7
11
13
17
19
23
29
31
37
41
43
47
53
59
...
```

Since you're learning, I'll give you some unsolicited style comments as well :)

- Don't use hd and tl.  Prefer pattern matching.  Then the compiler can tell you the cases you missed.  E.g.

  let rec sieve found toTest =
      let h = List.hd toTest
      and t = List.tl toTest in

would be

```
let rec sieve found = function
  | h :: t -> ...
  | [] -> Error handling...
```

- Don't use x = [].  Use pattern patching.

  match x with
  | [] -> ...
  | h::t -> ...
- Use anonymous functions rather than short (i.e. <= 1 line) named single use functions:

  let doesntDivide x = (x mod h <> 0) in
  let nonDivisors = List.filter doesntDivide t in

  let nonDivisors = List.filter (fun x -> (x mod h <> 0)) t in
- Use imperative features sparingly.

Comment: I couldn't disagree more about your recommendation of using anonymous functions. `List.exists hasDivisor p` is clear, and so is `List.filter doesntDivide t`. Your versions with anonymous functions aren't. Names are documentation. The subexpression `x*x` in `x*x + y*y` does not deserve a name, but `(fun x -> (x mod h <> 0))` does (quick: what is its intent?)

Comment: I will emphasize short.  The intent of the body of this particular function is as easy to determine the intent as the English text, and doesn't add one more name to need to remember (albeit for only a single line of code).

Answer (score 4):

Your algorithms that you claim are the Sieve of Eratosthenes actually are not; they use trial division instead of sieving, which is easy to spot by looking for a comparison of a remainder (the mod operator) to zero. Here's a simple implementation of the Sieve of Eratosthenes, in pseudocode instead of Ocaml because it's been a long time since I wrote Ocaml code:

```
function primes(n)
    sieve := makeArray(2..n, True)
    for p from 2 to n
        if sieve[p]
            output p
            for i from p*p to n step p
                sieve[i] := False
```

That can be optimized further, though for small limits like n = 2000000 there is little point in doing so; in any case, a sieve will be very much faster than the trial division that you are using. If you're interested in programming with prime numbers, I modestly recommend this [essay](http://programmingpraxis.com/essays) at my blog.